# jQuery do not run "if" after load

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coffeescript

All my js scripts are working, but this is not working

```
 $("img").each(function() {
      if ($(this).height() > 100) {
        return $(this).after("<p class='tasr'>FOTO © TASR</p>");
      }
    });
```

When I load page, it's not work, but when I copy this script do chrome-console, it work perfect.

My coffee script:

```
jQuery $(document).ready -> 
    $("img").each ->
        if $(this).height() > 100
            $(this).after("<p class='tasr'>FOTO © TASR</p>")
```

EDITED:

This is my dirty code: [My javascript code from coffeescript](http://pastebin.com/f70wM6Ls)

Comment: Chrome console* show any error?

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5P4Ed/1/), so can I just ask if you've got your jQuery in a `$(document).ready()` wrapper?

Comment: No, code is ok for chrome, but I think it dont start after page load. When I delete if statement, it's ok, but I need it only for big images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be down to the fact that the images havent finished loading yet and so return a height and width of 0.

You probably want to use `.load()` function on the image which will be triggered once the image loads and therefore will have a width and height greater than 0.

This would also explain why it is working in the chrome console since by then the images will have loaded.

**EDIT: Something worth noting mentioned by @zzzzBov in a comment below is that the cache in browsers will often stop the image calling the load function on a standard refresh.  To get around this you just need to have a function with all your code in which you call from both the .load function and inside the document ready function**

If this is your html:

```
<img id="img1" src="example.jpg" />
```

Then you can write something along the lines of this in your script.  Note this is off the top of my head so it might be slightly wrong.

```
function doStuff() {
    //I normally do a check here to see if the image width/height is 0 if it is then I dont bother
    //executing the rest

    //I do however sometimes need to do stuff when the image has not yet loaded which can be done here.

    //do stuff with the image, you could also pass parameters if needed.
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    doStuff();
});

$('#img1').load(function() {
    doStuff();
});
```

Comment: The unfortunate part about images is that caching in some browsers will prevent them from ever triggering the `.load` event. Proceed with caution.

Comment: yup so you have a function called both in the document ready and in the load function.  This is how I do it on my website which relies on image widths and it works perfectly.

Comment: Will I change $(document).ready to load? Sorry, I don't understand how I use your code

Comment: I will put an example in the answer above.

Comment: perfect, but I have simple bug. It added me 10x <p>tasr</p>. Because It run after load every image. Thank you very much

Comment: If you want it to do it once after all images have loaded then you need to count how many img tags you have and incrememnt that counter till it equals the count of images, then execute `doStuff()`.  If you just want it once after for example the first image then have a flag set to false first then once the first image is loaded set it to true.  If the flag is true then dont execute doStuff.